# How to Install-Package a pre-release nuget package?

Tags: powershell, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, terminal.gui

This package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Terminal.Gui/1.0.0-pre.5

`Find-Package` shows the pre-release versions if I use `-AllowPrereleaseVersions`.

```bsh
PS> Find-Package -Name Terminal.Gui -AllowPrereleaseVersions -AllVersions

Name                           Version          Source           Summary
----                           -------          ------           -------
Terminal.Gui                   1.0.0-pre.5      nuget.org        Console user interface toolkit for .NET applications.
Terminal.Gui                   1.0.0-pre.4      nuget.org        Console user interface toolkit for .NET applications.
Terminal.Gui                   1.0.0-pre.3      nuget.org        Console user interface toolkit for .NET applications.
Terminal.Gui                   1.0.0-pre.2      nuget.org        Console user interface toolkit for .NET applications.
Terminal.Gui                   1.0.0-pre.1      nuget.org        Console user interface toolkit for .NET applications.
Terminal.Gui                   0.90.3           nuget.org        Console user interface toolkit for .NET applications.

...
```

However, `Install-Package` fails:

```bsh
PS> Install-Package Terminal.Gui -RequiredVersion 1.0.0-pre.5
Install-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'Terminal.Gui'. Try Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.


PS> Install-Package -Name Terminal.Gui -AllowPrereleaseVersions -RequiredVersion 1.0.0-pre.5
Install-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'Terminal.Gui'. Try Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.
```

Comment: Why just don't copy a `Install-Package Terminal.Gui -Version 1.0.0-pre.5` command from package page? Works from my side